# boost::bind to concatenate strings in std::transform

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I am trying to concatenate two string using boost::bind inside std::transform

Assuming that my class has two methods to get two strings (first and second) and the conatiner is vector of strings, I am trying to do as follows

```
struct Myclass
{
   std::string getFirstString() {return string1}
   std::string getSecondString() {return string2}

   private:
     std::string string1;
     std::string string2;
}

Myclass myObj;

std::vector<string > newVec;
std::vector<myObj> oldVec;
std::transform (oldVec.begin(), oldVec.end(), std::back_inserter(newVec), boost::bind(&std::string::append,boost::bind(&getFirstString,  _1),boost::bind(&getSecondString, _1 ) ) );
```

But, I get error saying

```
error: cannot call member function 'virtual const getSecondString() ' without object
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of oldVec, newVec, getSecondString, ...

Comment: And `getFirstString` too.

Comment: Why can't you just use `for` loop here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first is that you're taking the address of a member function incorrectly. You always have to specify the class, i.e. `boost::bind(&Myclass::getFirstString, _1)`.

The second is that you're then trying to bind `std::string::append`, which modifies the object it's called on. You really want `operator +`. Since you can't bind that directly, use `std::plus<std::string>` instead. So this is what it should look like:

```
std::transform(oldVec.begin(), oldVec.end(),
               std::back_inserter(newVec),
               boost::bind(std::plus<std::string>(),
                           boost::bind(&Myclass::getFirstString, _1),
                           boost::bind(&Myclass::getSecondString, _1)
                          )
              );
```

Or you can use Boost.Lambda instead. And while you're at it, use Boost.Range, it's awesome.

```
namespace rg = boost::range;
namespace ll = boost::lambda;
rg::transform(oldVec, std::back_inserter(newVec),
              ll::bind(&Myclass::getFirstString, ll::_1) +
                  ll::bind(&Myclass::getSecondString, ll::_1));
```

Comment: Excellent. Everytime I think I know how to use boost::bind, I am beaten. Als, found this                           boost::function<std::string(std::string, std::string)> f =
    boost::bind(&std::string::append, _1, _2);

Comment: Stop using `append`. It doesn't do what you want. It modifies the string you call it on in place. It's bad enough that putting that bind into a `boost::function` taking the strings by value even compiles - I don't want to make a guess at what exactly it does.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are looking for a fashion way (one line code) to solve your problem, you can do this using for_each and lambdas:

```
std::for_each(oldVec.begin(), oldVec.end(), [&newVec](Myclass& mc) -> void { newVec.push_back(mc.getFirstString() + mc.getSecondString()); });
```

Comment: Yes. Anything using boost. I don't have access to C++11 yet.

Answer (score 0):

using your comment to the first answer, maybe you could use Boost.Foreach:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(Myclass const& it, oldVec) {
  newVec.push_back(it.getFirstString() + it.getSecondString());
}
```

btw, your question is badly written, so i'm free to assume that you're actually storing *copies* of `Myclass` in the vectors.

Comment: You might want to replace that `auto` with `std::string`, or it's still C++11.

Comment: And if you can use `auto` then you don't need `BOOST_FOREACH` anyway!

Comment: @justsomebody, I agree that the question could have been written better. I am sorry, I took few things for granted.